# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. File.Copy

Tags: c#, winforms, copy

I'm trying to copy png file into part of my project folder, but when I try I get this error.

The process cannot access the file '....../Image.png' because it is being used by another process.

I can assure you no other programs are accessing the file, and I have all my winforms designer windows close, as well as any other applications or windows.

This is the code I am using, I have tried all the other answers on this site and nothing works, any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

## region Asset Import Functions

```
    private void button_ImportAsset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Default to the directory which contains our content files.
        string assemblyLocation = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        string relativePath = Path.Combine(assemblyLocation, "../../../../Content");
        string contentPath = Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = contentPath;

        openFileDialog1.Title = "Load Asset";

        openFileDialog1.Filter = "PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|" +
                            "DDS Files (*.dds)|*.dds|" +
                            "BMP Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|" +
                            "All Files (*.*)|*.*";

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Creates new png version.
            string newFileName = ((openFileDialog1.FileName));

            string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            File.Copy(filename, newFileName, true);

            // Creates new xnb version.
            string outFileName =
            STATIC_CONTBUILDER.BuildXNBFromFile((openFileDialog1.FileName));

            // Copies the asset from the temporary build directory to the assets directory.
            File.Copy(
                Path.Combine(STATIC_CONTBUILDER.contentBuilder.OutputDirectory, outFileName),
                Path.Combine(STATIC_CONTBUILDER.pathToContent, outFileName),
                true);
        }

        Do_Refresh_XNB_Asset_List();
    }

    private void Do_Refresh_XNB_Asset_List()
    {
        listBox_Assets.Items.Clear();
        string[] lst_Files =
        Directory.GetFiles(STATIC_CONTBUILDER.pathToContent, "*.xnb", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        for (int i = 0; i < lst_Files.Length; i++)
        {
            listBox_Assets.Items.Add(
                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
            lst_Files[i]));
        }

    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: That exception message is only accurate for a user of debugged programs.  When you are developing, it should read: "You can't access the file, you've already got it opened and probably forgot to use the Dispose() method."

Comment: Side note: for public samples try to avoid ALL-CAPS naming convention (most of C# naming guidelines recommend subtle casing for identifiers like camelCase).

Comment: Alexei, my programming tutor asked us to name the class that way i'm afraid.

Comment: Hans, I receive no error message when developing because the error only appears when build the code, and try to import a file into my winforms project, the attempt to copy it fails and then produces that error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears that you are copying the file over it self.

```
string newFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;

File.Copy(filename, newFileName, true);
```

Comment: After this File.Copy(filename, newFileName, true); also itis coming same error

Comment: You'll need to provide another name, as what is written, is the error, pointed out.

Comment: 6 years later, this same thing happened to me. Different code and different APIs but I somehow ended up trying to copy a file over itself. God!